# Как правильно выполнить проверку chekbox через if()?

Tags: javascript

```js
'use strict'
let login = document.getElementById('fnameInput');
let email = document.getElementById('lname');
let password_1 = document.getElementById('password_1');
let password_2 = document.getElementById('password_2');
login.focus();

function validate() {
  if (login.value != '') {
    if (email.value != '') {
      if (password_1.value != '' && password_2.value != '') {
        if (password_1.value == password_2.value) {
          let infoPassword = document.getElementById('information');
          infoPassword.classList.remove('badregistration')
          infoPassword.classList.add('registration');
          infoPassword.innerHTML = 'вы успешно зарегистрировались!';
          return true;
        }
      }
      let infoPassword = document.getElementById('information');
      infoPassword.classList.add('badregistration');
      infoPassword.innerHTML = 'пароли не совпадают';
      return false;
    }
    let infoPassword = document.getElementById('information');
    infoPassword.classList.add('badregistration');
    infoPassword.innerHTML = 'ВЫ НЕ ВВЕЛИ @email!';
    return false;
  }
  let infoPassword = document.getElementById('information');
  infoPassword.classList.add('badregistration');
  infoPassword.innerHTML = 'ВЫ НЕ ВВЕЛИ ЛОГИН!';
  return false;
}
```

```css
.method_registration {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 40%;
  width: 30%;
  min-height: 400px;
  min-width: 300px;
  max-width: 600px;
  max-width: 400px;
  background: rgb(225, 222, 243);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.h1Form {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  color: rgb(58, 52, 62);
}

.form {
  color: white;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 80%;
  height: 50px;
  background: rgb(58, 52, 62);
}

span {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

.checkbox {
  background: green;
}

.registration {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  color: green;
}

.badregistration {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  color: red;
}

.inputForm {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  background: rgb(69, 65, 220);
  margin: 20px auto;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<form method="post" class="method_registration">
  <h1 class="h1Form">Регистрация</h1>
  <p class="formP"><input placeholder="логин" class="form" type="fname" name="fname" required id="fnameInput"></p>
  <p class="formP"><input placeholder="email" class="form" type="lname" name="lname" required id="lname"></p>
  <p class="formP"><input placeholder="пароль" class="form" type="password" required name="password_1" id="password_1"></p>
  <p class="formP"><input placeholder="пароль" class="form" type="password" required name="password_2" id="password_2"></p>
  <input class="inputForm" value="Регистрация" type="button" onclick="validate()">
  <p><input id="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="checkbox"><span>Я не робот</span>
    <p id="information"></p>
</form>
```

Comment: А ещё советую добавить больше информации: что конкретно не понятно и не получается, какой результат хотите получить и т.п.

Answer (score 2):

За это отвечает значение свойства `checked`

```js
const btn = document.querySelector('button');
const chk = document.querySelector('input');
const p = document.querySelector('p');

btn.addEventListener('click', ()=> {
  if (chk.checked) {
    p.textContent ="да"   
  } else {
    p.textContent ="нет"   
  }
}, false)
```

```html
<input type="checkbox">
<button type="button">проверить</button>
<p></p>
```